# Are Tor version and Tor link connection version same?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Tor version format is explained in [this link](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#VersionNumbers). In [Tor specification](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/blob/ec13d2e0c62bcfe6c982176196631c5a5ec1c471:/tor-spec.txt) (section 4.1), I found what they call "Tor link connection version" which based on my understanding could be one, two or higher.. my questions are these two versions the same? If not where can I find information about the tor link connection protocol version? If they are same, is the minor number corresponds to the link connection protocol version?

Thanks in advance!